# cordova phonegap error 1 while build apk

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-build

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

  > Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
  >   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:

  > BUILD FAILED
  >      Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  >
  > ```
  > Total time: 7.291 secs
  > ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"E:\nissagaza\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug
  > ```
  >
  > -b E:\nissagaza\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
  >       You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
  >       Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"E:\nissagaza\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b
  >   E:\nissagaza\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
  >   -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.